# Python appending to a file concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading

I wrote a simple program in Python:

```
from random import random
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def write_to_file(i):
    sleep(random())
    with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{i}\n")

for i in range(20):
    Thread(target=write_to_file, args=[i]).run()
```

I'd expect this program to write numbers from 0-19 to test.txt in random order. Instead, the program writes 0-19 in order, and it takes a few seconds to complete, signifying that it executed threads one after the other, in order.

How does this work? Does `with open(...)` block every other thread from running that also has `with open(...)` on the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the run method, change it to start, the run method is to call the main thread, equivalent to the ordinary function, start will only create a new thread, you wait a few seconds here because you set sleep(random()), you can comment this line:

```
from threading import Thread

def write_to_file(i):
    with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{i}\n")

for i in range(20):
    Thread(target=write_to_file, args=[i]).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does with open(...) block every other thread from running that also has with open(...) on the same file?

No, it doesn't.

`run` method of a thread starts and joins the thread which means that it waits for a thread to be joint for every iteration. To make it parallel you must call `start` instead of `run` then `join` all threads at once.

```
from random import random
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def write_to_file(i):
    sleep(random())
    with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{i}\n")


threads = []

for i in range(20):
    thread = Thread(target=write_to_file, args=[i])
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```